# Are events supported in Google Analytics for Mobile?

Tags: mobile, google-analytics

I'm trying to set up server side tracking of events on the mobile flavour of my web server through the usage of the JSP version of [google analytics for mobile](http://code.google.com/intl/ca/mobile/analytics/docs/web)

I'm trying to use the utme parameter to track a determinate event, but I'm checking the Analytics results page a day after and I'm not seeing the expected events (I've triggered them myself so that wouldn't be the problem), even though I'm seeing the tracking of the navigation seems to work as expected.

I know this parameter does not explicitly appear in the mobile parameter list, but it does appear in the [complete list](http://code.google.com/intl/ca/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingTroubleshooting.html#gifParameters) of parameters, which is linked from the mobile page as a reference.

Long things short: Is the use of the utme parameter supported in the mobile (JSP) version of Google Analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The utme parameter is currently not supported in the google analytics for mobile implementation. However, you can use this project:

http://code.google.com/p/serversidegoogleanalytics/

Which supports events, is very simple, and works with php 5.2

A sample implementation for this project would be the following:

```
<?php
/**
* SSGA example
*/

include("ssga.class.php");

$ga = new Elements_Tools_Serversideanalytics();
$ga->setAccountId("UA-123456789-1");
$ga->setCharset("UTF-8");
$ga->setHostName("localhost");
$ga->setLanguage("en");
$ga->setPageTitle("SSGA example");
$ga->setPageView("/index.php");

/**
* Send events
*/

$ga->setEvent("Test", "iPad", "12345433454323", "124");
$ga->createEvent();

$ga->setEvent("Another Test", "iPad", "12345433454323", "21");
$ga->createEvent();


?>
```

There is also a more complete project here, it requires php 5.3:

http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/